# jQuerty: Scroll to bottom of div (height of content inside)

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have created chat that works perfectly. I am trying to make my div scroll all the way to the bottom.. Div height is `calc(100% - 60px);`. That div loads messages from database through PHP. I have found many of questions here, but no one scrolls all the way to the bottom.

I have used now:

```
$('#allMessages').animate({
   scrollTop: $('#allMessages').get(0).scrollHeight
}, 2000);
```

Well am sure the problem is silly, but I really don't know how to fix..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code sample does work for me. I implemented it like this:

```js
const $messages = $("#messages")
  $("#scrollToBottom").click(() => {
    $messages.animate({
        scrollTop: $("#messages")[0].scrollHeight
    })
  })
```

[See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/qu5xntom/)

---

If this doesn't work for you, the problem may lay somewhere else. Are you performing this action before you loaded content into it? Make sure that the code is called after you loaded everything into it.

---

Say you're loading your data with jQuery, for example with `$.ajax` (or get, etc.)

It should look something like this then:

```js
  function scrollToBottom() {
    $messages.animate({
      scrollTop: $messages[0].scrollHeight
    })
  }


  $.ajax({
    url: 'your-data-source',
    // Some other params
    success: (data) => {
      $messages.html(data) // Replace your content somehow

      // After it has been replaced, update the scroll value
      scrollToBottom()
    }
  })
```

When having a lot of asynchronous operations which have to operate in sequence, the nesting level will get quite deep. At which point I recommend looking at the `Promises` API in JavaScript, which helps you deal with this.

Comment: Well I think both actions are playing at same time..

Comment: I have delayed jQuery function with your code. Seems to work good so far..